# Filter services on services.msc or windows services console alternative

Tags: windows, service, mmc

I'm trying to set a custom management console for helpdesk accounts with a reduced set of our programs running as Windows Services so they can visually start/stop/manage them. Services.msc is not what I'm looking for unless I could filter the services I want. I've been testing Sysinternals Autoruns and NirSoft ServiWin but they can't make complex filtering and save it for later. Powershell commands give status information and allow to start/stop but I'm looking something similar to a MMC.

Do you know such a tool? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There's a freeware utility called ServiWin that will do what you would like:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/serviwin.html

It has a /LoadFromList command line argument:

> Starting from version 1.50, you can instruct ServiWin to load only the
>   desired services by using the /LoadFromList command-line option. You
>   can specify the desired services by their name, display name, or the
>   .exe file. Here's a few examples:
>
> serviwin.exe /LoadFromList WZCSVC Spooler Schedule LmHosts Browser
>   RemoteRegistry serviwin.exe /LoadFromList svchost.exe serviwin.exe
>   /LoadFromList "C:\WINDOWS\System32\ups.exe"

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of creating a custom windows services list with filters would be using PowerShell and WinForms and will not require much effort since you are already familiar with the commands.

Here are some nice guides to start with:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stephap/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form/
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_GUIs_in_Windows_PowerShell_1.0_with_WinForms

Comment: I've ended up developing my own .net c# console. It's in alpha status but functional. It uses windows system dll's to ensure same behaviour as services.msc console with the commands sent to a service but adding the desired extra functionality (filter, search, multiserver connections, etc.) I hope to release it public after some beta-testing (and after the proper make-up to my messed up code because I'm a sysadmin, not a real developer by now).

Comment: @SergiMuñozSanmartín This sounds fabulous. I came here after getting annoyed by services.msc and its lack of power (e.g. you cannot multiple select and right-click to action, you cannot "stop and disable" or "enable and start" etc.) Did you get anywhere with this? I would love to see your alternative to services.msc using Windows DLLs